# How do I make my Python substitution not greedy?

Tags: python, regex

My Python subn  is too greedy.I am modifying an OFX file (XML or SGML), contained in string ofx.

I want to remove any buy or sell that contains a particular hard-coded CUSIP , and to not affect any other.  A buy starts with a [BUYMF] and ends with the next [/BUYMF].  A sell starts with a [SELLMF] and ends with the next [/SELLMF].  If either contains 123456789, I want to remove each of those from the ofx string.

I added question marks after all of my wildcards in the string

```
(ofx,sub_count)= re.subn( \
   r'<(SELLMF|BUYMF)>.*?<UNIQUEID>\s*?123456789.*?</(SELLMF|BUYMF)>' \
   ,'',ofx,  flags=re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
```

I expected only the buy and sell transactions would be removed, but instead
a big block of transactions gets removed.

Edit after I marked my solution and then corrected it:
All criticisms and comments were correct and very useful. Thanks.

Comment: Along with the description it could help if you added a few examples including input and expected output.

Comment: The first `.*?` matches _everything_ until "an 123456789" is encountered,  _including_ any sells and buys in between, that's _why_ it is too greedy.

Comment: In prep for my adding the example input, I realized my flaw. There was no buy or sell of 123456789 but there was a 123456789 for a dividend. I see how the Python is indeed selecting the smallest match, because per my intention, there should have been no match.

I don't have the answer yet to just remove the buys and sells of 123456789, but I see why my code failed. Thanks. folks. I am not sure of the solution yet, but I now can more effectively come up with a solution.

Comment: No need to add "status" messages in the title. If you find a solution, feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: Possible solution:
Every transaction will have a `<DT` early, before the 1234567.  If
I run into another transaction before the SELLMF or BUYMF, then I have wandered
too far.  So with a negative look-around, I can poison any match
covering more than one transaction.

The code section becomes
```
(ofx,sub_count)= re.subn( \
 r'<(SELLMF|BUYMF)>.*?<UNIQUEID>\s*?123456789((?!<DT).)*</(SELLMF|BUYMF)>' \
   ,'',ofx,  flags=re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
```

I will be able to test now for lack of greed, and I will wait for the
case to occur where I want to actually remove the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

```
(ofx,sub_count)= re.subn( \
 r'<(SELLMF|BUYMF)>(?:(?!MF>).)*<UNIQUEID>\s*?123456789(?:(?!MF>).)*</(SELLMF|BUYMF)>' \
   ,'',ofx,  flags=re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
```

Works as modified above. I found my first "solution" was flawed.
There may be better solutions. Thanks to all who commented.